# _msize Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I spend a lot of time trying to find out why I have an assert in this code.

If there is no destructor in the class, it's work well.

Can you explaine, why I have an Assert whit the class containing destructor.

I dont want to know the number of element in the array. I Just want to understand the Assert when there is a destructor in the class.

With Visual C++, the "new" call the "malloc" function.

=====================================================================================

More detail:

With: CTheClass* pArrayTheClass = new CTheClass[1];

In debug, in the _heap_alloc_dbg_impl() function,
you can find the following line of code:
   blockSize = sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader) + nSize + nNoMansLandSize;

where:
 sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader) : 32
 nSize : 4
 nNoMansLandSize : 4

After that, the memory is allocated (withHeaderBlock), 
and the function return the pointer to the data part.

And at the end of "operator new[] " in the "new2.cpp" file,
 this data pointer is return, to the program allocation.

But
   With:
   CTheClassWithDestructor* pArrayTheClassWithDestructor = new CTheClassWithDestructor[1];
   is nearly the same thing...

but the nSize is equal to 8;   sizeof( int) + 4 bytes

But this time, even if at the end of "operator new[] we have the dataPart pointer.
In the main program I receive this pointer with an offset of 4.

And if I substract 4 from the pointer there is no assert when I call the _msize() function.

That explain the Assert.
The assert is cause bt this offset of 4.

### But why we have this offset of 4 ?

Conclusion

This offset of 4 bytes contain the number of element.

If the class have a destructor, the compiler reserve 4 bytes to hold the number of elements in the array.

If there is no destructor to call, we don't have this extra 4 bytes as offset.

Thank's 
Marc

```
#include <malloc.h>

class CTheClass
{
private:
    int TheValue_;
};

class CTheClassWithDestructor
{
public:
    ~CTheClassWithDestructor()
    {
        int TheValue_ = 0;
    }
private:
    int TheValue_;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int size;

CTheClass* pArrayTheClass = new CTheClass[1];
size = _msize(pArrayTheClass);
delete [] pArrayTheClass;

CTheClassWithDestructor* pArrayTheClassWithDestructor 
                   = new CTheClassWithDestructor[1];
size = _msize(pArrayTheClassWithDestructor);           /// ASSERT On this line
delete [] pArrayTheClassWithDestructor;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> With Visual C++, `new` calls the `malloc` function.

This is partially true:  the `new` expressions in your code do call `operator new` to allocate memory and `operator new` does indeed call `malloc`.  But the pointer to the initial element that is yielded by the `new` expression is not necessarily the pointer obtained from `malloc`.

If you dynamically allocate an array of objects that require destruction (like your `CTheClassWith_string` type), the compiler needs to keep track of how many elements are in the array so that it can destroy them all when you `delete` the array.

To keep track of this, the compiler requests a slightly larger block from `malloc` then stores some bookkeeping information at the beginning of the block.  The `new` expression then yields a pointer to the initial element of the array, which is offset from the beginning of the block allocated by `malloc` by the bookkeeping information.

Comment: I have add a "More detail:" section @James McNellis

Comment: Those four bytes are used for the bookkeeping information (they store the number of elements to be destroyed).  For `CTheClassWith_int`, no destruction is required so the compiler does not allocate space for the bookkeeping information.

Comment: No more string, now I have a destructor.  I will try to find the bookkeeping information next week.  @James McNellis

Comment: The bookkeeping information seams just to be the number of elements in the array.  Is't true ?  @James McNellis

Comment: Yes, currently that is the case.